# Using CLion IDE for code developing for QNX6.5 Neutrino targets

Tags: c++

I am trying to use CLion IDE as my development environment for QNX6.5 Neutrino. I want to write a `CMakeList.txt` to automate my build process. I want to cross-compile my source code in CLion which the output can be on the target embedded system.

I found some hints to how prepare the `CMakeList.txt` file, in this file the local `C_Compiler` and `CXX_Compiler` addresses are specified:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER qcc)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET ${arch})

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER qcc -lang-c++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET ${arch})
```

But the following error shows up:

> is not able to compile a simple test program

How can I configure CLion for that purpose?

I also need to use Valgrind for analyzing my code behavior inside QNX.

Comment: What does CLion have to do with all this? It's just a frontend that triggers CMake. In that light, you need to search for "cmake crosscompile C++" on the web, it should turn up a few results.

Comment: I already search for that ("cmake crosscompile C++") but i didn't manage to find out a way. Cmake application also shows up the same error message!!

Comment: I am trying to configure my build tool chain for QNX6.5 in a general IDE different from QNX Momentics. (e CLion or QTCreator)